# Forward lightly my eclipse runtime on a static web page

Tags: javascript, eclipse, web, runtime, xtext

Maybe my question is irrelevant, but I am currently working on a small DSL on Xtext to produce code that is intended to be compiled with Coq.

I was wondering if there was an easy and light way to forward my xtext-runtime (or more generally eclipse runtime) onto a web page, I have looked at dsl-forge (which does not match my current xtext version) and the [web editor](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/330_web_support.html) page of xtext website, but it seems quite complicated.

Any recommandations or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have very little experience on this, but using Xtext's web support is indeed not straightforward (although feasible, see below). Nowadays I would rather go for Xtext's LSP support (available since Xtext 2.11).

[LSP](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) is a protocol that allows to split the editor and the "language server", which is the actual language implementation (providing features like autocompletion, etc.). The main advantage is that once you have a language server you can easily add support for the language to most IDE/editors (both web and desktop based).

See [here](https://blogs.itemis.com/en/integrating-xtext-language-support-in-visual-studio-code) for an article showing how an Xtext language can be supported in VS Code thanks to LSP and [here](https://www.typefox.io/blog/xtext-lsp-vs-xtext-web) for an article comparing Xtext Web Integration and Xtext LSP.

You may also be interested in Eclipse Theia and Eclipse Che (for a cloud-based IDE — maybe not "lightly"):

- Github repo demonstrating a Theia Application with DSL support through an Xtext Language Server: https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-xtext
- Medium article demonstrating the integration of an Xtext-based DSL in Theia: https://medium.com/@jan.koehnlein/domain-specific-languages-in-theia-8838aee1279

#### Xtext Web Integration

(*Disclaimer: memories of a school project made some time ago*)

Basically, by checking "Web Integration" when creating a new Xtext project, Xtext will generate:

- a XtextServlet, that must be served in a custom server. It provides autocompletion, validation and will be called by the front-end *on each keystroke*.
- a JavaScript file, that must be integrated to your Web Editor of choice (I think this is the most tricky part). It provides syntax highlighting and is responsible of communicating with the XtextServlet.

It's then up to you to use those components to build a Web editor.